# HTTP upload gives 403 error

Tags: tridion

We are setting up new Content Delivery server for Tridion 5.3 SP1 environment.
New website is created for HTTPS upload, as per the instructions given in the instruction manual.  When we browse httpupload website from content delivery server using localhost:20000/httpupload.asp sometime it gives 500 error or sometime it given 403 error.  Can someone let us know exactly were we are going wrong.  Even we tried accessing httpupload.asp from different machine there also it gives 500 error.

Note : Modify permissions are given to IUSR AND IWAM user on work folder.

Comment: If the error is 500, is there an error message you can share? Or is there an error in the windows event log?

Comment: Error message : The website declined to show this webpage HTTP 403 Most likely causes: This website requires you to log in. What you can try: Go back to the previous page. More information This error (HTTP 403 Forbidden) means that this program was able to connect to the website, but it does not have permission to view the webpage. What I am trying to do is browse httpupload website and see the tridion default message "TCDFileUpload.FileUpload.1.1 error '80004005' TCDFileUpload::SaveToDisk(): no data to save (due to 'GET' instead of 'POST', maybe?) /httpupload.asp, line 9"

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have enabled directory browsing in IIS.

Also make sure that the 'asp' extension is present in the Extensions in IIS.